# http insecure protocol when compiling Go program for hyperledger

Tags: go, compiler-errors

I am using

```
go version go1.9.1 windows/amd64
```

When I try to compile using:

```
go get -u --tags nopkcs11 
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim
```

I get

```
package github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim: cannot download,
http://gerrit.hyperledger.org/r/fabric uses insecure protocol
```

I can't change to `https://github.com/hyperledger/...` and https is not allowed.

If you go to [this source](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/chaincode4ade.html#choosing-a-location-for-the-code)  and go to *Pulling it all together*, you can see the source code I am using.

This is the beginning of it.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim"
    "github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer"
)

// SimpleAsset implements a simple chaincode to manage an asset
type Appointment struct {
}

// Init is called during chaincode instantiation to initialize any
// data. Note that chaincode upgrade also calls this function to reset
// or to migrate data.
func (t *SimpleAsset) Init(stub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface) peer.Response {
```

How do I successfully compile my program?

Comment: There are no imports from gerrit in that repo. Are you sure all your sources are up to date? Your `go get -u` command has a newline before the package name; so if that actually is the command you're running, you're not updating the source.

Comment: BTW, if you look at the help output for the `get` command, there is an `-insecure` option to allow this, but it looks like it should work correctly in the first place.

Comment: @JimB - I put in the newline to make it more readable. I hate when I have to scroll right to see the line.

Comment: Gotcha. Still, running `go get github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim` works for me, so you must have something different in your code. Is it possible you have an `insteadOf` in your git config that is changing the URL?

Comment: I will need to look at my Go setup. I can't find the protos/peer or shim so something is wrong in my setup.  Thank you very much.  The -insecure worked btw.